# Preg match fails simple compare

Tags: string, preg-match

I'm trying to use the code below to compare two strings. The preg_match doc page says "preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject". As the output shows, the result is 1 even though the strings are different? Please explain my mistake.

```
    $cmp_text = 'sue, smith';
    $text = 'sue, smith shelly';

    $pos = preg_match('/' . $cmp_text . '/', $text); 
    if ($pos == 1) { 
      echo 'matched: ' . $cmp_text . ' is the same as ' . $text . '<br>';
    } else echo 'no match';

    echo 'pos '.$pos;
```

The output from the above is

```
    matched: sue, smith is the same as sue, smith shelly
    pos 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are passing to [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as the pattern is `/sue, smith/`

You are matching `sue, smith` in `sue, smith shelly` which will [find a match](https://regex101.com/r/fdiwa8/1/)

You could [add anchors](https://regex101.com/r/zLjOSk/1) for the beginning `^` and the end of the string `$`.

Then what you pass to preg_match as the pattern would be `/^sue, smith$/`

Try to update this line:

`$pos = preg_match('/' . $cmp_text . '/', $text);`

to this line:

`$pos = preg_match('/^' . $cmp_text . '$/', $text);`

Comment: Thank you. The anchors worked. But is $matches needed? I don't need to know where or what was returned. I just need to know if it matched, which I use $pos for. Is that not the correct way to do it?

Comment: No you dont need that. I forgot to remove it. Yes you can do it like that. From the docs: preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.